# Scrapy installed, but won't run from the command line

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to run a scraping program I wrote for in python using scrapy on an ubuntu machine. Scrapy is installed. I can import until python no problem and when try `pip install scrapy` I get

> Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): scrapy in /system/linux/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

When I try to run scrapy from the command, with `scrapy crawl ...` for example, I get.

> The program 'scrapy' is currently not installed.

What's going on here? Are the symbolic links messed up? And any thoughts on how to fix it?

Comment: Are you importing scrappy beforehand.

Comment: Run `python --version` and `python -c "import scrapy"`.

Comment: re: Aiden, I'm trying to run it from the command line. I can import scrapy into a python script no problem. Re: Alex, I ran both commands and am still getting "The program 'scrapy' is currently not installed. "

Answer (score 35):

Without sudo, pip installs into $HOME/.local/bin, $HOME/.local/lib, etc.  Add the following line to your ~/.bashrc or ~/.profile (or the appropriate place for other shells):

```
export PATH="${PATH}:${HOME}/.local/bin"
```

then open a new terminal or reload .bashrc, and it should find the command.

Comment: this is only temporary fix, you should add this line in bashrc
`nano ~/.bashrc` then add this line 
`export PATH="${PATH}:${HOME}/.local/bin"` finally restart bashrc `source ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 21):

I had the same error. Running scrapy in a virtual environment solved it.

1. Create a virtual env : `python3 -m venv env`
2. Activate your env : `source env/bin/activate`
3. Install Scrapy with pip : `pip install scrapy`
4. Start your crawler : `scrapy crawl your_project_name_here`

For example my project name was `kitten`, I just did the following in step 4
`scrapy crawl kitten`

NOTE: I did this on Mac OS running Python 3+

Comment: Thank you! The Scrapy docs should really mention this.

Answer (score 7):

I tried the following `sudo pip install scrapy` , however was promtly advised by Ubuntu 16.04 that it was already installed.
I had to first use `sudo pip uninstall scrapy`, then `sudo pip install scrapy` for it to successfully install.
Now you should successfully be able to run scrapy.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem and solved using following method. I think scrapy is not usable by the current user.

1. Uninstall scrapy.

   `sudo pip uninstall scrapy`
2. Install scrapy again using -H.

   `sudo -H pip install scrapy`
3. Should work properly.

Comment: What does `-H` do?

Comment: sudo pip install scrapy

Answer (score 1):

If you install scrapy only in virtualenv, then scrapy command isn't exists in your system bin directory. You could check it like this:

```
$ which scrapy
```

For me it is in(because I sudo installed it):

```
/usr/local/bin/scrapy
```

You could try full path to your scrapy.
For example if it is installed in virtualenv:

```
(env) linux@hero:~dev/myscrapy$ python env/bin/scrapy
```

**Note:** [We recommend installing Scrapy inside a virtual environment on all platforms.](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. `sudo pip install scrapy` fixed my problem, although I don't know why must use `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you activate command that is
"Scripts\activate.bat"

Answer (score 0):

A good way to work around is using pyenv to manage the python version.

```sh
$ brew install pyenv

# Any version 3.6 or above
$ pyenv install 3.7.3
$ pyenv global 3.7.3

# Update Environment to reflect correct python version controlled by pyenv
$ echo -e '\nif command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then\n  eval "$(pyenv init -)"\nfi' >> ~/.zshrc

# Refresh Terminal
# or source $~/.zshrc
$ exec $0 

$ which python
/Users/mbbroberg/.pyenv/shims/python
$ python -V
Python 3.7.3

# Install scrapy
$ pip install scrapy
$ scrapy --version
```

Reference:

- https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac

Answer (score -6):

scrapy crawl is not how you start a scrapy program. You start it by doing

```
scrapy startproject myprojectname
```

Then to actually start a scrapy program go into myprojectname/spiders and then you can call

```
scrapy crawl "yourspidername"
```

To have scrapy create a spider you can cd into your directory and execute

```
scrapy genspider mydomain mydomain.com
```

Additionally, you can test if your scrapy actually works by executing

```
scrapy shell "google.com"
```

All this information can be found in their [Documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/index.html).
If something happens then you have actually installed scrapy and you are crawling (haha) your way to success!

P.S. Scrapy does not work well on Python3 so if you're running on there and you still have troubles, use Python 2.7!