# Scrapy installed, but won't recognized in the command line

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I installed Scrapy in my python 2.7 environment in windows 7 but when I trying to start a new Scrapy project using `scrapy startproject newProject` the command prompt show this massage

```
'scrapy' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Note:

- I also have python 3.5 but that do not have scrapy
- This question is not duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37757233/scrapy-installed-but-wont-run-from-the-command-line)

Comment: can you try `scrapy.py` ? Can you check the `PATHEXT` variable?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre What is scrapy.py and PATHEXT? 
I am new in scrapy first time tried to start working reading [this](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.1/intro/tutorial.html#creating-a-project)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I did that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [official documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.1/intro/install.html).

- **Set environment variable**
- **Install pywin32**

Answer (score 3):

[Scrapy should be in your environment variables](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.1/intro/install.html#intro-install-platform-notes). You can check if it's there with the following in windows:

```
echo %PATH% # To print only the path
set # For all
```

or

```
printenv # In linux
```

Make should scrapy is in your *path* and if it's not, add it to your path and it should (probably) resolve your problem. I said probably, since it might be caused by other issues you have not mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Anaconda or Miniconda, try updating the `conda` command as follows:

`conda update -n base -c defaults conda`

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If updating `conda` doesn't bring the expected result, try to install `scrapy` in the current environment with `pip install scrapy`.

You should see a "successfully installed" message, and some info about the path, like this:

```
> "WARNING: The script scrapy.exe is installed in
> 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\Scripts'
> which is not on PATH"
```

If you try running it again...

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\Scripts\scrapy
```

... you will see that it works. You should update/add the path info, and the shell knows how to fix the rest. I have just tried this on my computer using a new installation of Python & WSL2.

Answer (score 0):

same problem here and check up different installation [guide link](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-guide-to-conda-environments-bc6180fc533)
and run below in anaconda prompt:

> conda update scrapy

now working perfectly with scrapy startproject cmd

Answer (score 0):

write below command in command line

```
conda update -n base -c defaults conda
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue and tried multiple solutions listed.

I identified that when using conda, even though you can install scrapy through pip, you would need to install it through conda for the command to work.

conda install scrapy

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same issue, and I fixed by closing VS code and reopen VS code through Anaconda Navigator