# Can anyone help me with this? "The term 'scrapy' is not recognized as a cmdlet name, function, script file or operable program."

Tags: python, scrapy, anaconda, conda

PS C: \ Users \ Acer \ projects \ worldometers \ worldometers> conda activate virtual_workspace
PS C: \ Users \ Acer \ projects \ worldometers \ worldometers> scrapy crawl countries
scrapy: The term 'scrapy' is not recognized as a cmdlet name, function, script file or operable program. Check the spelling of the name or, if a
path has been included, see if the path is correct and try again.
In line: 1 character: 1
+ scrapy crawl countries
+ ~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo: ObjectNotFound: (scrapy: String) [], CommandNotFoundException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId: CommandNotFoundException

Comment: scrapy is not set in your environment variables. This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39486965/scrapy-installed-but-wont-recognized-in-the-command-line should help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add scrapy to your environment variables or try `python -m scrapy crawl countries`

Comment: how can I add scrapy to my environment?

Answer (score 1):

If this message is shown on your Visual Studio Code terminal
And if you have anaconda installed on your system,
 try these two solutions:
1- Run the crawler code on **Anaconda Powershell Prompt**(Not even in your systems default CMD)
The code I entered in the Powershell was `scrapy crawl divar -o prices.csv -t csv`
*"divar" was the name of my crawling project*

*prices.csv is the name of my output I want to get*
2- Open your VScode from **Anaconda Navigator**, then run your code in the Terminal
Also please be sure that:
1- "scrapy" is installed and updated correctly on your system
2- You're in the correct file direction
3- Essential packages are updated on your system
[crawling](/questions/tagged/crawling)[scraping](/questions/tagged/scraping)[anaconda](/questions/tagged/anaconda)[scrapy](/questions/tagged/scrapy)[vscode](/questions/tagged/vscode)[python](/questions/tagged/python)