# I installed Scrapy in windows but when using "scrapy startproject foldername" it gives me error as "the term scrapy is not recognized"

Tags: python, scrapy

installed scrapy using pip install scrapy but When using scrapy startproject foldername it gives me error as-
scrapy: the term 'scrapy' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of
the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

I tried to create a project folder using scrapy but it didnt recognized the term 'scrapy'

Comment: You need to update your [path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39486965/scrapy-installed-but-wont-recognized-in-the-command-line).

Comment: One silly possibility could be to restart the terminal. Sometimes the terminal doesn't recognize newly installed packages and only does that after you close and open the terminal again.