# Scrapy command on cmd doesn't working even tho scrapy is installed

Tags: python, cmd

So I downloaded scrapy and tried to use scrapy commands in the cmd. Here's some screen : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uePqb.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xssgW.png) translation for the second one : Scrapy isn't recognised as an internal or external command. It does that for every python library and python is installed. I use python 3.11

I tried to reinstall python and scrapy but nothing helps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scrapy installed, but won't recognized in the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39486965/scrapy-installed-but-wont-recognized-in-the-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

1. When you type **JUST** a command (ie. just the command name like 'Scrapy', 'Python') in your command prompt, your system tries to find the command by looking in your `PATH` environment variable. If it finds the command there, it will be executed. If it doesn't find the command there, you'll get an error.
2. If your command isn't in your `PATH` environment variable, then you need to specify the full path to the command e.g. `C:\\users\<user_name>\mycommand`

In summary, find out the location of the `scrapy` executable file and then type that full path in your command prompt

Comment: how can I add it to the path environment variable ? And how can I find out scrapy executable files because when I try to search it, I can't find any executable file.

Comment: the command "pip show scrapy" gives me the path. But when I go to that path, there is nothing.