# permanent fix to scrapy not found

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a problem with scrapy on my server,each time I open I have to do the answer on [scrapy not found][1]

[1]: [Scrapy installed, but won't run from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37757233/scrapy-installed-but-wont-run-from-the-command-line) `export PATH="${PATH}:${HOME}/.local/bin"` it does work but I am looking for solution that fixes this permanently (I have sudo access)

Error: `bash: scrapy: command not found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to append this command to your `~/.bashrc` file so that it gets executed each time you SSH onto the server.

Log in to your server and run the following command like it is suggested in [Scrapy installed, but won't run from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37757233/scrapy-installed-but-wont-run-from-the-command-line):

```
echo 'export PATH="${PATH}:${HOME}/.local/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: thanks, to be sure this will work on Ubuntu and Debian right?

Comment: Yes, it should.